# Java 4 to Java 7 generics code translator

Tags: java, generics

I have a lot of Java 4 code. All the time I see something like:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new Person());
// later
Person person = (Person) list.get(0);
```

I want to change it to be more Java 7 compliant:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Person());
// later
Person person = list.get(0);
```

Can the process of adding `<TypeParameters>` and removing unnecessary casts be automated?

In other words - is it possible to create "Java 4 to Java 7 generics code translator"? Maybe there are already tools doing that?

Comment: Generics was added in Java 5.  Perhaps you want to automatically change Java 4 (last pre-generics version) to Java 7?

Comment: @rgettman You're absolutely right, thank you, I've edited my question.

Comment: IIRC IntelliJ IDEA can do this.. or it was some other IDE, I'm not sure. I don't use it. Try to google, this will be quite a common problem.

Comment: I'd advice you to upgrade from Java 4 to Java 5, to Java 6 and then finally to Java 7 though. This is a lot easier if you automated tests, but you could at least run simple user tests. There may be edge-cases were this kind of process is needed. Functionality could theoretically be deprecated in Java 5, then removed in Java 6 and re-implemented as something else in Java 7.

Comment: May not be completely possible to automate if your code depends on accidentally adding two different types of objects to the same structure. But an automation with a set of warnings or manual actions to be done by the user would seem very possible.

Comment: I once faced with this problem. I just used find/replace on my whole code base. First checked my working code into Git, to be safe. Then I searched for "List " (note the space) and replaced with "List<> ", intentionally introducing compiler errors. Then I fixed all those manually, by filling in the right generic parameter. Although it was manual, I was brought to the right spot by the compiler each time, so it wasn't too hard. As a final sanity check, I did a search all for "List<> " (note the space) and found nothing. It's an approach worth trying if you don't have thousands of references.